# Impact of creating UIImage from CGImage for every animation frame

Tags: ios

In my current project I'm displaying procedurally generated animated image data by creating a CGImage from a custom back buffer and display the animated frames on a UIImageView by creating UIImage from the source CGImages.

I'm wondering if this is a rather heavy weight operation that involves lots of copying of pixel data and if someone would recommend a better approach. I don't really have a performance problem on the device but faster is always better.

Comment: Can you draw the "animated" image data right on a UIView?

Comment: @MarcusAdams I'm not sure. Can I? That's why I'm asking :)

Comment: What is the target frame rate for your animated images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a a view's layer to display the image rather than UIImageView.

```
view.layer.contents = (__bridge id)cgImage;
```